# color and font selection by user in php

Tags: php, image, fonts, transparency, gd

I have this code of mine which is actually uploading an image from my system and also creating an image with transparent background and then merging the two images. But now I want that I should provide user an option fro selecting the fonts from the list that I provide and should also be able to select color as per his choice from my given list of colors. I don't understand how to provide choice to the user for fonts and colour. Kindly suggest me some editing in my code.

```
    <?php
    //Set the Content Type
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    #dispaly the image
    $file=$_GET['file'];
    $text=$_GET["text"];
    // echo file_get_contents($file);
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0 , 0, 0);
    $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

    imagecolortransparent($im, $black);

    //text to draw
    //$text="helllooooooooooooooooooooo";
   //font path
   $font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSans.ttf';
   // Add the text
   imagettftext($im, 15, 0, 15, 15, $blue, $font, $text);

   $dest=imagecreatefrompng($file);
   //$src=imagecreatefrompng($im);

   imagealphablending($dest, false);
   imagesavealpha($dest, true);

   imagecopymerge($dest, $im, 15, 15, 0, 0, 400, 400, 100);

   imagepng($dest);

   imagedestroy($dest);
   imagedestroy($im);

    ?>
```

here is my form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Image Editor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1><u>Add Text To Your Image..!!</u></h1></center>
    <form action="upload.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Select image to upload:<br></h3>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter your text">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

for color, how will i use form??

Comment: using a form to let the user choose a color and font ?

Comment: I guess `'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSans.ttf';` is a fixed file path in ubuntu? it's better to use a relative path. And where is your form?

Comment: ya, its a fixed file path in ubuntu. but i m not able to understand how to provide different options for fonts and colors. Is there any way possible that automatically user gets all the optiions present in my fonts folder for writing text???